# Render problem with Collapse Toolbar Layout

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, render, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have the project and one of fragment use the Collapse Toolbar Layout.
Until recently, everything was fine. But last time i faced in Android Studio with the problem of render of the Collapse Toolbar Layout. For example below the example of layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

        
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/favorite"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="this is text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView> </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is that NestedScrollView hidden after rendering in Android Studio and sometime appear when i remove next prompt:

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

But it appear in the left-top corner of fragment.
Android Studio shows the next error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat$AccessibilityActionCompat
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.updateAccessibilityActions(AppBarLayout.java:1882)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.setHeaderTopBottomOffset(AppBarLayout.java:2118)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.setHeaderTopBottomOffset(AppBarLayout.java:1446)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderBehavior.setHeaderTopBottomOffset(HeaderBehavior.java:158)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1781)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1427)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1446)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout_Original(CoordinatorLayout.java:953)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23694)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23680)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23694)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23680)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23694)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23680)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23694)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23680)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:377)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

What i had did:

- invalidate caches
- clean and rebuild the project

Also i tried create new empty project and test the layout code in it and new project work correctly.

Please let me know how i can resolve this problem?

Comment: What i found. In build.gradle i have dependencies 'implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.1''. After rollback to version 1.10.0 Collapse Toolbar Layout work properly.

Comment: I've run into this as well. I opened a bug about it, here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301737107

Comment: @Vasily The rollback actually works.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Here is my solution for the preview bug:

> tools:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"

Include the line inside your "com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout"

Comment: This worked for me. I hope Google can resolve this so we do not have to use such workarounds.

Comment: Works like charm, on Android Studio, dependencies and plugins up to date.