# Android Layout Render Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, render

I have a RecyclerView list and recently a "Render problem" appeared in the layout, activity_main.xml:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ACTION_SCROLL_IN_DIRECTION
at androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat$Api34Impl.getActionScrollInDirection(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.java:5592)  [*the rest of the stack error is shown below*]

An online google forum for Android bugs suggested that issue might be a bug in
"implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0'" that was addressed in the next alpha release.
So, I loaded "implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.13.0-alpha01'" and that did not eliminate the issue.

Any ideas on this issue and how to fix it?

```
activity_main.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"  >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/action_logo"
                android:title="@string/action_logo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/action_logo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_toolbar_logo_foreground"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:showAsAction="always" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.
AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"  >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/filterListTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sortListTV"
            android:text="@string/filter"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/quickListTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:text="@string/quicklist"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:tooltipText="sort quicklist by default"
            tools:targetApi="o" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sortListTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:text="@string/sort"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_sort_white_24dp"
            app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/ic_sort_white_24dp" />

        <include layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_below="@+id/quickListTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"  />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:contentDescription="@string/newcardbutton" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Full stack of the render problem:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ACTION_SCROLL_IN_DIRECTION
at androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat$Api34Impl.getActionScrollInDirection(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.java:5592)
at androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat$AccessibilityActionCompat.<clinit>(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.java:748)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.updateAccessibilityActions(AppBarLayout.java:1846)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.setHeaderTopBottomOffset(AppBarLayout.java:2082)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.setHeaderTopBottomOffset(AppBarLayout.java:1458)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderBehavior.setHeaderTopBottomOffset(HeaderBehavior.java:158)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1792)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1439)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1458)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout_Original(CoordinatorLayout.java:953)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23694)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23680)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23694)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23680)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23694)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23680)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23694)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23680)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:377)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Is this just in the Android Studio layout editor? Or are you encountering this on devices? If it's purely in the IDE, your results might vary by IDE version.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, the "Problems" output is coming from Android Studio.  No rendering issue so far on a smartphone device where the app is loaded.  I am using latest Studio stable version, Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving:

```xml
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.
AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

from the `RelativeLayout` (?!?) to the `AppBarLayout` itself. That's based on [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301737107#comment3) on the root issue. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77150653/render-problem-with-collapse-toolbar-layout).

Comment: Bingo, render issue disappears after moving the scrolling code line from RelLayout to the AppBarLayout.  Answer upvoted and accepted, cheers!

Comment: New problem has arisen:  the TextViews that I have in the layout file (basically a few headers above the RecycerView list) are now hidden because the RecyclerView is taking up all of the screen space below the Toolbar.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: @AJW: I guess set up better constraints on your `<include>` element. I am guessing that is where your `RecyclerView` lies, as it is not in the layout in your question.

Answer (score 5):

From Google's Issue Tracker, a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development,

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/300719286:

jg...@google.comjg...@google.com #4Sep 22, 2023 10:58AM

The issue is that in Android Studio Giraffe, the rendering is done using a version of the Android platform corresponding to API 33, where the field ACTION_SCROLL_IN_DIRECTION does not exist. To workaround this issue, you can either use Android Studio Iguana which renders layout with the Android platform compatible with API 34. Or more simply, you can select API 33 in the API menu of the layout editor instead of API 34.

and

an...@google.coman...@google.com #5Oct 5, 2023 05:26PM
Thank you for your patience while our engineering team worked to resolve this issue. A fix for this issue is now available in:

Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 7

Android Gradle Plugin 8.3.0-alpha07

We encourage you to try the latest update.

If you notice further issues or have questions, please file a new bug report.